# How to fix a deleted module in Python 3.7.0

Tags: python, datetime

I have been practicing Python from a book and I think I accidentally deleted the **datetime** import.

I had used...

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

and kept getting an error. I found out that this was because I saved the file as **datetime.py**. I renamed the py file as **showingdates.py** and deleted the **datetime.py** I had saved in my folder in my documents tab. I also deleted the file called I think **datetime.py** in another folder that Python created called **__pycache__**.

So now when I run my program...

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

the return in Geany after execute is completely empty.

Did I delete the datetime module, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you print the output of `datetime.now()`? Or is that the entire script?

Comment: That was the entire script I've used.

Comment: @Cpytron You should use `print()` to display the result.

Comment: Are there any `*.pyc` files in that directory? Also, try running this script in a new folder entirely. Luckily, you can't permanently delete standard modules by misnaming a file.

Comment: Thanks! The book isn't using anything but Python's IDLE so I didn't know I had to print it in Geany.

    print (datetime.datetime.now())

Worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script
Seems like you missed print statement.

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```